# Problems with High-Speed PWM Module

Tags: c, embedded, pic, microchip, pwm

I would like to use a dsPIC33EP32MC204 microcontroller for motor control application. However I am unable to make the High-Speed PWM work (no PWM pulses on the PWM2H pin), even though i was following the User Manual and the Family Reference Manual.  Here is my code:

```
void Init_PWM(void)
{
    PTCONbits.PTEN = 0;  //PWM module is disabled
    PTCONbits.PTSIDL = 0;  // PWMx time base runs in CPU Idle mode

    PWMCON2bits.FLTIEN = 0;     // Fault interrupt is disabled and the FLTSTAT bit is cleared
    PWMCON2bits.ITB = 0;        // PTPER register provides timing for this PWM generator
    PWMCON2bits.MDCS = 0;       // PDCx register provides duty cycle information for this PWM generator
    PWMCON2bits.MTBS = 0;       // PWM generator uses the primary master time base for synchronization and as the clock source
    PWMCON2bits.IUE = 0;        // Updates to the active PDCx registers are synchronized to the PWMx period boundary
    PTCON2bits.PCLKDIV = 0b000; // PWM Input Clock Prescaler 
    PWMCON2bits.CAM = 0;        // Edge Aligned PWM
    PWMCON2bits.DTC = 0b10;     // Dead time function is disabled

    IOCON2bits.PENH = 1;        // PWMx module controls PWMxH pin
    IOCON2bits.POLH = 0;        //  PWMxH pin is active-high
    IOCON2bits.OVRENH = 0;      // PWMx generator controls PWMxH pin
    IOCON2bits.PMOD = 0b01;     // PWM I/O pin pair is in Redundant Output mode

    PHASE2 = 0;                 // No Phase Shift
    PTPER = 0x4E20;             // Period register 

    PTCONbits.PTEN = 1;         //PWM module is enabled
}
```

Related code from the main() function:

```
TRISBbits.TRISB12 = 0;

Init_PWM();   
PDC2 = 0x2710; //Duty Cycle
```

I would be grateful if someone could tell me why can't I see any PWM pulses after completing the attached configurations. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Robert Harvey put this question on hold, but the reasons given are not good. What appears in the post conforms to the guidelines. The question needs help with formatting so the code shows up correctly. The PWM function block in the dsPIC33EP32MC204 is tricky to setup. If I can I will post a comment with a link to  working code.

Comment: Please find code that answers the question asked by Barney on my Github [here](https://github.com/dsoze1138/Microchip/blob/master/PIC/33E/33EP32MC204/33EP32MC204_PWM/33EP32MC204_PWM.X/main.c). If the hold on this question is released I will post an answer.

Comment: Thank you @Dan1138. Your code worked.

Comment: This question is asked with enough information to offer a complete answer. It was placed on HOLD within minutes of being asked. Edits to improve the question did not result in releasing the hold. Based in Robert Harvey answers to other question he appears to have little relevant experience with dsPIC33EP32MC204 devices. The short answer is that the some of the PWM Special Function Registers require a device specific method to be unlocked for writes. See compiler docs on __builtin_write_PWMSFR() function.